# iOS: Drawing just portions of a UImage

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, image-manipulation, quartz-core

I am trying to draw just a custom portion of a `UIImage` (i.e.: I would like to *reveal* the portion of the `UIImage` user touches) and I am having reasonable results by using `mask` property of the `layer`.

Something like this on my `UIView`:

```
UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[maskPath setLineWidth:10.0];
[maskPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(10.0, 10.0)];
[maskPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(100.0, 100.0)];
CAShapeLayer *shapeMaskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
shapeMaskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
[self.layer setMask:shapeMaskLayer];
```

Then, on `drawRect`:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [img drawInRect:rect];
}
```

It works. I am just seeing the portion of the image defined by `maskPath`.

However, doesn't look that that's the best way of approaching this issue. So my question is: **What would be the best way of drawing just a custom portion (it could be any shape) of an image in iOS SDK?**.

Answer (score 4):

One thing you could try is simply clipping instead of creating an extra layer.  e.g.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [maskPath setLineWidth:10.0];
    [maskPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(10.0, 10.0)];
    [maskPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(100.0, 100.0)];

    CGContextAddPath(ctx, maskPath.CGPath);
    CGContextClip(ctx)
    [img drawInRect:rect];
}
```