# UIView that is shaped like a UIBezierPath?

Tags: ios, uiview, calayer, uibezierpath

Is it possible on iOS to make a regular UIView in some CGRect and add subviews to it and then tell that container UIView something like this:

```
containerView.layer.path = someClosedUIBezierPath
```

?

And will then all of the subviews also be curved according to it's parent container view?

I know that every UIView has it's own CALayer and that would be the starting point for me.

I saw examples with animations but I don't see nothing like above (maybe because it isn't there :))

Comment: i didn't try this one but i think it should help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10220145/653513 (it's done in `drawRect` though)

Comment: well that does not look very nice since I need user touches also. I thought it would be easy.

Answer (score 7):

This is a little late, but maybe it will help someone:

You can clip a view to a bezier path by using a `CAShapeLayer` and the view's layer's `mask` property:

```
CAShapeLayer shapeMask = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] initWithFrame:containerView.bounds];
shapeMask.path = someClosedUIBezierPath.CGPath;
containerView.layer.mask = shapeMask;
[shapeMask release];
```

Comment: Well, I use CAShapeLayer and mask but not for this problem. I decided not to push this problem and rearranged my UI.