# UITableview cell merge animation

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-animation

I'm trying to do an animation similar to this on in a UITableView.The slide in animation would be pretty straightforward by modifying the constraints of the content or maybe the transform of the cell using `CATransform3D`.

The main problem here is, how can I merge two views by simultaneously modifying the `cornerRadius` of both the view as one view is moving into the screen such that both views appear to be merged(Like in the GIF below). So, my question is,

1. Is it possible to create an animation where the content of two `UITableViewCell` can be merged like in the GIF below.
2. If that isn't possible, how can this animation be done on two `UIView` which aren't in a `UITableView`. I might be able to figure out a workaround if I know how to do this animation on two simple `UIView`.

I've been trying to search and figure out a way to do this for quite sometime but I have no clue on how to do this. Any help or pointers on how to go about to solve this problem will be much appreciated. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: You will need to use a custom path that is not a subview of any cells and is under the cells. You should calculate the frame union for the two labels and morph that path from one state to the other.

Comment: @the4kman Can you post some link that I can use to read about it?

Comment: Here is a useful question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18375822/tweening-interpolating-between-two-cgpaths-uibeziers

Comment: Very similar . https://stackoverflow.com/a/12073142/4601900